# DB Structure : Ok or not?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing an application management business (sales, suppliers, customers, products, ...) for a new company. To begin, I need to create a database. Could you please tell me if the BD scheme bellow is good and optimized ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `SIRET` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `enable` ENUM('YES', 'NO') DEFAULT 'YES',
  `level` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY SIRET (SIRET)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

// contactType can be one of the 3 values : email, phone, fax
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contactType` (
  id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `contactType` ENUM('email', 'phonenumber', 'faxnumber')
  `mobile` ENUM('YES', 'NO') default 'NO',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY type (contactType)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `SIRET` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactType` varchar(50) NOT NULL, // A reference to contactType just above
  `contactref` varchar(50) NOT NULL, // Phone number, fax number or email adress
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY type (SIRET)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `SIRET` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY type (SIRET)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supplier` (
  id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `SIRET` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY type (SIRET)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `industry` (
  id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `industry` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY type (activite)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entreprisePerIndustry` (
  id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `industry_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL, // Chemical, Computer, Consulting, ...
  FOREIGN KEY (industry_id) REFERENCES industry(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  `SIRET` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY type (industry_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Any reason not to use InnoDB and utf8 rather than MyISAM and latin1? http://tag1consulting.com/MySQL_Engines_MyISAM_vs_InnoDB helps for first (basically, use InnoDB!), and it's rare to not need some utf-8 stuff, “” and ‘’ aren't in latin1.

Comment: Depends on the queries/insertions/updates

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing about the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are few **TIPS** which can helps you to create better DB

- Change table engine from `MyISAM` to [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) if you want make foreign key constrains to work.
- **AUTO INCREMENT** DataType should be **UNSIGNED INT**. this will double the range.

  ```
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`
  ```
- if a column value chosen from a list of permitted values then change dataType to  [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) .In your case `enable`, `level` can be turned into **ENUM** dataType

  ```
  `enable` ENUM( 'y', 'n' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y' COMMENT 'y:yes; n:no' `
  ```
- add [foreign key relation to](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

  `contacts`.`contactType` with  `contactType`.`id`

  `entreprisePerIndustry` .`industry`  with `industry`.`id`

### update

I have created basic and optimized table structure ( AFAIK ).

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_company`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_company` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `siret` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `enable` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y' COMMENT 'y:yes; n:no',
  `level` enum('1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `last_updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_contact`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_contact` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `siret` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contact_type` enum('email','phone','fax') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'email',
  `contact_ref` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Phone number, fax number or email adress',
  `last_updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `siret` (`siret`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

...
...
```

[`complate structure is here`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af1a1/1)

Comment: I'd be very wary of using `ENUM('0','1')` as the values have indexes of `1` and `2` respectively (an index of `0` corresponds to the empty string `''`): this could lead to considerable confusion if one neglects to quote values properly.  Perhaps the `BOOLEAN` type is more appropriate in such cases (albeit it's a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`), but otherwise I'd at very least advocate `ENUM('Yes','No')` or similar.

Comment: setting `DEFAULT` value will reduce the mistakes.

Comment: Not especially.  Consider `UPDATE mytable SET mobile = 1;` which will actually set `mobile` to `'0'`!  Or `UPDATE mytable SET mobile = '2';` which will not generate an error but will instead set it to `'1'`.  Or `SELECT mobile + 1 FROM mytable WHERE mobile = '1';` which will return `3`.  It's fraught with problems.  As [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/enum.html) says: "*For these reasons, it is not advisable to define an `ENUM` column with enumeration values that look like numbers, because this can easily become confusing.*"